# two norms are equivalent

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I have a homework question that ask to prove two parts and I did one part and not sure how to prove the second part.
The question says:
Let $(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ and $(Y,\|\cdot\|_Y)$ be two normed vector spaces and assume that $T \in L(X,Y)$ is an isomorphism. Define a scalar valued function $\|\cdot\|_T$ on $X$ by
$\|x\|_T = \|T(x)\|_Y$ for all $x \in X$. Prove that $\|\cdot\|_T$ defines a norm and show that it is equivalent to the original norm $\|\cdot\|_X$.

As I mentioned, I was able to prove the four axioms of the norm, but for the second part that $\|\cdot\|_T$ and $\|\cdot\|_X$ are equivalent, we need to show that there are $m, M >0$ such that
$m\|x\|_X \leq \|x\|_T \leq M\|x\|_X$ for all $x \in X$. I am not sure how exactly to start with this inequality.

Comment: where is $\lVert\cdot\rVert_T$ defined? Did you mean $\lVert x\rVert_T\,\colon =\lVert T(x)\rVert_Y$?

Comment: @CSquared, yes this is the definition.

Comment: okay, just making sure. you should fix that typo then

Comment: @CSquared, I did, thank you!

Comment: It looks like the definition $\|{\cdot}\|_T$ does not depend on $\|{\cdot}\|_X$ at all, so you'll need to prove that $\|{\cdot}\|_T$ is equivalent to _every_ norm on $X$ -- which is hopeless because it is not true. (If $X$ is infinite-dimensional then there exist norms on it that are not equivalent).

Comment: (This assumes that $T$ is just a _vector space_ isomorphism. However, if "$T$ is an isomorphism" means that $T$ preserves the _norm_ in addition to the vector space operations, then $\|{\cdot}\|_T$ is trivially _equal to_ $\|{\cdot}\|_X$ so there's nothing to prove).

Comment: @Troposphere In standard terminology $T$ is an isomorphism between normed linear spaces if it is linear, bijective and $T,T^{-1}$ are both continuous. If it preserves norm is called an isometric isomorphism.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: I see. With such a strong assumption the claim is of course (almost trivially) true ...

Answer (score 1):

In Functional Analysis an isomorphism of normed linear spaces is a bijective map $T$ such that $T$ and its inverse are both continuous. So we have $\|Tx\| \leq M\|x\|$ where $M=\|T\|$ (the operator norm). Also, $\|x\| =\|T^{-1}(TX)\| \leq \|T^{-1}\| \|Tx\|$ so $\|Tx\| \geq m\|x\|$ where $m=\frac 1  {\|T^{-1}\|}$.

Comment: Than you very much. That's make sense.